# Set variable depending on specific cmake custom target

Tags: variables, cmake

I have a target defined like this in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(Doxygen)
if(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    set(INTERNAL, no)
    configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile @ONLY)
    add_custom_target(doc
        ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile
        DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen" VERBATIM
    )
endif(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
```

Now I want to add a new custom target with the name `doc_internal`, but this time the variable `INTERNAL` has to be set to `yes`.

This comes down to not setting the variable `INTERNAL` once globally, but having the variable depend on the custom target.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just clarificatio: Is there `@INTERNAL@` in the `Doxyfile.in`? You want to have 2 doxygen targets in one CMakeLists.txt and reuse the code you have shown?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So the configure_file target also has to be executed twice. We could make a `Doxyfile` and a `Doxyfile_internal` both from `Doxyfile.in` but with different values of the `INTERNAL` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example `configure_file` can output different Doxyfiles for different targets

```
macro(gen_doxy target INTERNAL)
  set(doxyfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile_${target})
  configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile.in ${doxyfile} @ONLY)
  add_custom_target(${target} ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${doxyfile} ...)
end macro()
```